# Convert string in '\\x00\\x00\\x00' format to unsigned char array

Tags: c++, string, byte, shellcode

Say I have a string as so:

```
std::string sc = "\\xfc\\xe8\\x82";
```

how could I convert the sc string into the equivalent of

```
 unsigned char buf[] = "\xfc\xe8\x82";
```

I'm trying to convert a string containing shellcode into a unsigned char array.

I have tried the following:

```
char buf[5120];
strncpy(buf, sc.c_str(), sizeof(buf));
buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = 0;
```

This seems to store strings into the char array I need the char array to store/represent bytes.

When I print:

```
//example 1
unsigned char buf[] = "\xfc\xe8\x82";
printf("%s", buf);
```

The console outputs:

```
ⁿΦé
```

When I print:

```
//example 2
char buf[5120];
strncpy(buf, sc.c_str(), sizeof(buf));
buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = 0;
```

The Console outputs:

```
\xfc\xe8\x82
```

How do I convert the sc string into a unsigned char array so that when sc is printed sc will produce the same output of example 1.

Comment: Why are you using a string in the first place? vector of chars (or the plain array) would just work.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I am new to c++.

Comment: Why do you want an array? The string already uses an array under the hood. If you want a pointer to the underlying array, use `.c_str()` (read-only) or `.data()` (read/write).

Comment: @asrdelinx: your second example is perfectly valid C++. (Although `unit8_t` or `std::byte` would be "better" than unsigned char)

Comment: I'll add what I've attempted to give more context.

Comment: @asrdelinx -- HolyBlackCat has a valid point.  Why do you need to convert this to an unsigned char array?   The array you're looking for is already there -- why the unnecessary trip of creating an `unsigned char` array?

Comment: How is `sc` initialized in your real application? The first line of code you shared won't work. It's hard to know where to start answering this question because it's unclear up to which point your code works.

Comment: Because I'm sending the shellcode over the network and it's being stored in the string sc so I need to convert it to unsigned char array to allocate memory and execute it.

Comment: Your example 1 snippet is working.  When you use %s, printf will try to convery everything in the array to unicode, which is the symbols you are seeing.

Comment: @asrdelinx -- What do you mean by "to allocate memory"?  Your example shows no memory allocation.  It shows an unnecessary need to convert to an `unsigned char` array.

Comment: The purpose of the sc string is to convert into unsigned char array and use a shellcode injection technique (either function pointer or virtual alloc) to execute the converted sc shellcode payload.

Comment: `std::string sc = "\xfc\xe8\x82";` and `unsigned char buf[] = "\xfc\xe8\x82";` are literally the *exact same bytes* in memory, so a simple `memcpy()` or `strncpy()` or `std::copy()` will work, or you can type-cast the `(const) char*` pointer from `sc.c_str()`/`sc.data()` to `(const) unsigned char*`. But I suspect your `string` really contains `"\\xfc\\xe8\\x82"` (bytes `5C 78 66 63 5C 78 65 38 5C 78 38 32`) not `"\xfc\xe8\x82"` (bytes `FC E8 82`). If so, then you need to *parse* the individual `\xHH` sequences from the `string` data, such as with `sscanf()` or `std::istringstream`.

Comment: You're correct they are in \\x00\\x00 format I just discovered that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The literal `"\\xfc\\xe8\\x82"` as a string uses "\" as an escape character.  "\\" will be reduced to "\". As you would expect. So, if you print your given `std::string`, then the result will be:
`\xfc\xe8\x82`.

So, what you want to do now is: Create a char array containing those hex values, given in the original `std::string`.

Please note: Your statement `char s[] = "\xfc\xe8\x82";` will create a C-Style array of char, with the size 4 and containing:

```
s[0]=fc, s[1]=e8, s[2]=82, s[3]=0
```

In the example below I show 2 proposals for conversion. 
 1. Straight forward conversion
 2. Using C++ standard algorithms

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


// Hex digit String
std::regex hexValue{R"(\\[xX]([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))"};


int main ()
{   
    // Source string
    std::string s1 = "\\xfc\\xe8\\x82";
    std::cout << "s 1: " << s1 << "\n";


    // Proposal 1 ------------------------------------------------------

    // Target array
    unsigned char s2[3];

    // Convert bytes from strings
    for (int i=0; i<s1.size()/4; ++i ) {

        // Do conversion. Isolate substring, the convert
        s2[i] = std::strtoul(s1.substr(i*4+2,2).c_str(), nullptr,16);
        // Result is now in s2

        // Output value as tring and decimal value
        std::cout << s1.substr(i*4+2,2) << " -> " << std::hex << static_cast <unsigned short>(s2[i]) 
                  << " -> " << std::dec << static_cast <unsigned short>(s2[i]) << "\n";
    }

    // Proposal 2 ------------------------------------------------------

    // Get the tokens
    std::vector<std::string> vstr(std::sregex_token_iterator(s1.begin(),s1.end(),hexValue, 1), {});

    // Convert to unsigned int
    std::vector<unsigned int> vals{};

    std::transform(vstr.begin(), vstr.end(), std::back_inserter(vals), 
        [](std::string &s){ return static_cast<unsigned>(std::strtoul(s.c_str(), nullptr,16)); } );

    // Print output on std::cout
    std::copy(vals.begin(), vals.end(), std::ostream_iterator<unsigned>(std::cout,"\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

The second solution will eat any number of hex numbers given in a string